# How do i import jar files to Visual studio code?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, code-server

I followed everything written on the official website, but it doesn’t seem to work.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUtVG.png)

I also tried modifing the settings.json directly but that too didn’t seem to work.
Does anyone know what the problem may be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ##### Manage dependencies for unmanaged folder
>
> If your project is an unmanaged folder without any build tools. You can manage the dependencies by clicking the + icon or the - icon on the **Referenced Libraries** node or the items under it, or you can just directly drag your jar libraries to the node `Referenced Libraries`

[image]

Simple scripts can be imported directly. If it is a Java project, it is recommended to use build tools such as **Maven** to manage dependencies.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-project#_dependency-management